# Exclude control from UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net

I am using an updatepanel on my page I like to exclude a control from the update panel.

I tried to use the following code but did not work for me:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

Not sure how to exclude a control from the control panel.

Comment: What do you mean by "exclude" here?

Comment: If you want a control within UpdatePanel to perform a full postback - include it into triggers as a full postback trigger e.g.  `<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="myExcludedButton" />`